# Run Arquillian tests against Chrome headless in github actions

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, github-actions, arquillian-drone

I created a [JakartaEE Server Faces sample](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee-faces-sample) which used Arqillian Dron and Arquillian Graphene to test the faces web pages.

The tests are passed on my local system, but when set the headless chrome as web driver in Github action workflow like this(see the complete file [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee-faces-sample/blob/master/.github/workflows/maven.yml), by default it use  `phantomjs` webdriver):

```
    - name: Run integration test with -Parq-payara-embedded(chromeheadless)
      run: mvn clean verify -Parq-payara-embedded,chromeheadless
```

It is frozen at this step.

But I ran the same command(`mvn clean verify -Parq-payara-embedded,chromeheadless`) in my local system, it works. How to make the `chromeheadless` work on Github actions?

Comment: So if you try to test a plain html or jsp instead of a jsf page, it works?

Comment: @Kukeltje It works on local dev env. I think it is an env related problem. I've searched the official Github actions, but did not found how to set `chromeheadless`  for my test env in Github actions CI workflow file.